# How to cast Base Class based on type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, inheritance

Some one please suggest how to do the below scenario.

I have a case Class name BaseData and Derived class named DerivedData

```
Type classtype=Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseData)).GetType("DerivedData");
BaseData baseobject=  Activator.CreateInstance(classtype) as BaseData;
```

Now i want to cast the BaseData to DerivedData,Something like below.

Note: (baseobject.getType()) is invalid syntax.

```
DerivedData objderived= (baseobject.getType())baseobject;
```

Edited: I am trying to remove the if condition because BaseData got multiple DerivedData.

```
if (baseobject is DerivedData1)
{
  db.Set<DerivedData1>().Add((DerivedData1)data);
}
else if (data is DerivedData2)
{
  db.Set<DerivedData2>().Add((DerivedData2)data);
}
else if (data is DerivedData3)
{
  db.Set<DerivedData3>().Add((DerivedData3)data);
}
```

Comment: Is `DerivedData` type statically available in code, which needs this cast?

Comment: @Dennis do you mean instance of DerivedData?.DerivedData is inherited from BaseData.

Comment: No, I mean static reference to assembly, where `DerivedData` is declared. Technically, cast is simple: `var objDerived = (DerivedData)baseobject`. But this is allowed only if `DerivedData` is known statically. Actually, this looks like XY-problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve though?

Comment: @Dennis,@enkryptor The concern is , I have multiple DerivedData for example DerivedData1,DerivedData2,DerivedData3,ect.So based on the string i pass in GetType("DerivedData1") the activator will create the instance. thanks

Comment: So basically you're trying to find a class by it's name and instantiate it, right? Implying the class is provided by one of yours assemblies.

Comment: @enkryptor yes correct.

Comment: But what's the purpose? Are you trying to implement sort of a dependency injection? Why don't use a proper framework (say, MEF) for importing classes then..

Comment: That didn't explain why you are instantiating base class first, and then trying to cast it to a derivative. Why don't instantiate derivative? upd. it seems Dennis have a right guess

Answer (score 2):

According to your edit, and assuming, that:

- `db` is [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx);
- `BaseData` hierarchy exists only at code level (thus, types, derived from `BaseData`, are not in TPH, TPT, or TPCT hierarchy from the point of EF model);

just use [non-generic API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%28System.Type%29):

```
var baseobject = // create BaseData descendant somehow;
db.Set(baseobject.GetType()).Add(baseobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can reach the `BaseData` by referring to it directly can you reach the `DrivedData` also ?

```
Type classtype = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DerivedData)).GetType("DerivedData");
DerivedData dreivedobject =  Activator.CreateInstance(classtype) as DerivedData;
```

Comment: Activator will create new instance of DeriveData but i want to cast the existing object.Before casting i will be assigning value to the derived object.

Comment: if you type `DreviedData` in the code, does the compiler has problem or not? I mean can you see this type in compile time??

Comment: I have no compiler issue.DerivedData type is exists in the assembly.The concern is , I have multiple DerivedData for example DerivedData1,DerivedData2,DerivedData3,ect.So based on the string i pass in GetType("DerivedData1") the activator will create the instance. thanks